# Tableau - Max(day(var_data)) for a month condition

Tags: tableau-api

I have 4 dates in a month (4 weeks)
like:

```
var1
2001-01-10
2001-01-15
2001-01-20
2001-01-30
2001-02-10
2001-02-15
2001-02-20
2001-02-30
```

I want to creat a new var with just the max date in this month:
like:

```
var2=max(var1) for the same month
0
0
0
2001-01-30
0
0
0
2001-02-30
```

how can i do this?

Comment: Did you try Max and what is the result

Comment: the function in tableau max(date) like in the example the result is 2001-02-30 only

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you're after, do you only want to show the max DAY for a given month, for every month?

If so, create a table calculation with a formula like this:

```
{FIXED DATETRUNC('month',[date field]): MAX([date field])}
```

To explain:

- FIXED = apply the aggregate function to only these 'windows' for the calculation. Here we're fixing at the month level. But you could do several layers like month, category, subcategory
- : = after the colon you can apply the calculation that you want to do, in your case it's the maximum month

So bringing that together in a sentence, what we're doing is "For each date, truncate to the month level, then for each month, what's the maximum date?"

Hope that helped